# How do i get user images on twitter using Twitter API?

Tags: api, twitter, google-api, twitter-oauth, twitterapi-python

I'm trying to download users timeline images (including tweets images). How do i get user images on twitter using Twitter API.
[https://api.twitter.com/labs/2/tweets/1138505981460193280?expansions=attachments.media_keys&tweet.fields=created_at%2Cauthor_id%2Clang%2Csource%2Cpublic_metrics%2Ccontext_annotations%2Centities][1]

This API proved all the details about a single tweet. If any possible solution to get all images from a standard twitter app. Or this feature only available in premium account ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the [v2 User timeline endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-users-id-tweets):

`twurl "/2/users/786491/tweets?max_results=100&expansions=attachments.media_keys&media.fields=url,media_key"`

You can retrieve up to 3200 of the user's most recent Tweets using this method. You can get additional information by adding further [fields and expansions](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/using-fields-and-expansions) to the request, if you need them.